# DB Modeling : Parent child relation for users sharing an account

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a marketplace scenario wherein a user can view certain things. Once he registers as a seller or buyer in the marketplace he gets their identity and certain views/tasks.

I can have the following tables

```
  --> User (any user entering the platform)
  --> Seller (after registering as seller)
  --> Buyer(after registering as buyer)
```

A buyer or seller can share account so buyer can have other users under him.
In this case is it better to do a user_group table or use parent_id

Also a seller can become buyer (for other products also).Do I do it with a Role table.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
User
    userid PK
    username
        
Product
    productid PK
    productname

Transaction
    transactionid PK
    product FK, Product.productid
    seller FK, User.userid
    buyer  FK, User.userid
    
Parents
    parent, FK, User.userid
    child,  FK, User.userid
```

**PK**: primary key
**FK**: foreing key

The concept of seller and buyer only exists in the context of a transsaction.  Since a user can be both, it can be tracked in the transaction table.

For parents - child users, I think a parents table is better than a group here, since it will be easier to build multiple inheritance links between users.